# Do Google's Courgette works on Mac and Linux yet?

Tags: diff

Last time i checked, the google diff Courgette only works on Windows 32 Bit Platform and it is yet available on Linux and OSX. Is that still the case?

If yes what makes Courgette only works on windows and not cross platform? Isn't it just binary diff? And what do Chrome currently uses on Linux and Mac for diff updating?

Answer (score 0):

Courgette works on Linux and for ELF32. It [does not work for ELF64 yet](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124521).

Answer (score 0):

According to this design document, courgette knows enough assembly language to update pointers by a fixed amount to reduce the patch sizes:

http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette

In a 64-bit environment, the size of the pointers and the instruction set are different enough that making courgette work efficiently is not trivial.